# CSS mobile version of web site is zoomed in A LITTLE BIT when loaded (only whatchable with mobile device)

Tags: css, mobile, zooming, viewport, pinchzoom

I have set up a mobile web site of http://www.berlin-ra-kanzlei.de/ ... but for an unknown reason it always seems to be zoomed in just A LITTLE BIT (maybe 1 - 3%?). There is always missing some milimetres of the right side and I can zoom out with a pinch.

It also happens, when I am on the site and clicking another page. It just does not want to show the complete page from the beginning, although I have set the boxes to width: 100%;.

Btw, I have set

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Without it my layout goes bananas on mobile devices and setting it to a lower initial-scale does not help either. There is till missing a little bit on the right side.

But I do not want to forbid zooming! I just want to have it all seen on initial loading/visiting.

So, I think it has to do with some CSS values or so. Maybe I have set something over 100% width or so? Because if I zoom/pinch out after loading, it works just fine ... until loading another page of the web site, of course.

Thanks a lot in advance, mates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your box model for the the #container and #header divs to border-box:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

You may need to prefix this depending on what browsers you are supporting.
More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Thanks SO much. I was really losing the grip here. :)